# Add to wishlist with ajax

Tags: 7, commerce

How can i make **add to wishlist button** with **ajax** like **add to cart button** using  [Commerce ajax cart module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ajax_cart) .

Also in my view how to change the **add to wishlist** button text to **already added** if user has already added the product to wishlist.
I am using commerce wishlist module

Comment: which module and version you are using for whishlist?

Comment: Commerce Wishlist version-7.x-1.x-dev

Comment: Wishlist Block on click of Add to wishlist AJAX link is already fixed in 2.x; marking as fixed.  https://www.drupal.org/node/1951820

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called [Commerce Wishlist](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_wishlist)

Alternatively, for ajax functionality, you could use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to replicate a similar sort of functionality